# Terraform list ECS cluster container instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to get list of ids/arns of all EC2 container instances on ECS cluster, I tried with data source: aws_ecs_cluster but it only shows registered_container_instances_count - the number of registered container instances for the ECS Cluster without any information about them

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data source provided by TF that suit your needs, you can provide your own using [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). Using the external data source you can get any information that you want into your TF scripts for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Make sure to have boto3 module imported and the needed AWS permmisions

(not a Python or a Terraform expert)

```
terraform {}

data "external" "external_resource" {
  program = ["/usr/bin/python3", "${path.module}/list_instances.py"]

  query = {
    cluster_name = "CHANGE_ME"
  }
}
output "output" {
  value = data.external.external_resource.result
}
```

```
import boto3
import sys
import json


client = boto3.client('ecs')

def list_containers(cluster_name):
    # list all container instances id 
    response = client.list_container_instances(
        cluster=cluster_name
    )
    return response['containerInstanceArns']

def describe_container():
    # get terraform query json and assign it to a dict
    query=sys.stdin.readlines()
    terraform_respone_dic=json.loads(query[0])
    cluster_name=terraform_respone_dic['cluster_name']

    # get the container instances
    response = client.describe_container_instances(
    cluster=cluster_name,
        containerInstances=list_containers(cluster_name)
    )

    # get the instance id's and assign to a variable
    instances=list(map(lambda x:x['ec2InstanceId'],response['containerInstances']))
    # assign them to our original query json (dict)
    terraform_respone_dic['instances_id\'s']=instances

    # return as stdout
    output = json.dumps({str(key): str(value) for key, value in terraform_respone_dic.items()})
    sys.stdout.write(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    describe_container()
```

expected outputs :

`terraform apply`

```
Outputs:

output = tomap({
  "cluster_name" = "production"
  "instances_id's" = "['i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']"
})
```